# Flipping word animation effect

Tags: website-design, design, animation

I sometimes sees some effects on websites that allows you to flip the text, for instance

We are a `word` company.

Where `word` would flip around a few adjectives like `dynamics` or smth like that.

Can anyone please let me know what is the name of that effect?

Thank you,

**P/S:**  I know this may seems basic and I will close this question once I got the answer.

Comment: This doesn't need to be React or even JS, you can do it with CSS as well, so I edited your title. I have no idea how to call it other than *word replacement* or *rotating words*

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're looking for? I'm not entirely getting it from your description.

Comment: This reminded me of a flip clock, so if it hasn’t a name already, call it a “flip clock effect”. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_clock

Comment: @jazZRo Not quite the perfect one, but should be applicable to me!

Comment: @RoAchterberg I found it again, on this website, after the " WE ARE COMMUNITY ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I know what you mean - correct me if I am wrong. It's also not so basic ;)

### Intended effect

From my understanding you want an animation that goes somewhat like this:

- *0s - 1s*: We are a **dynamic** company
- *1s - 2s*: We are a **modern** company
- *2s - 3s*: We are an **ethical** company
- ...

### Battle plan

Funnily enough, I researched something like that a while ago and don't think it has *the one name*, mostly because it is composed of multiple effects:

- You need to switch between the different words (can be done in CSS and JS)
- You want some cool effect on transitioning - blur, spin, typing, whatever (probably going to be a CSS animation)
- You need some fixes and advanced CSS/JS trickery for the annoying stuff: some words being way longer and thus ugly, unintended line breaks, in the example above the "a/an" stuff, ...

That said, here is...

### ...a collection of possible relevant resources:

- [StackExchange q/a about replacing text without any big effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796213/css-text-animation-replace-text)
- [Code example for a kind of typing-new-words-effect](https://www.codeply.com/go/9BM4CF5m1m/css-only-typing-animation-word-replace) - by the way, `typewriter effect css` might be what you want
- [Guide for different way to swapping out text, not necessarily a looping animation tho](https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/)
- [Code example for replacing words in a loop with a kind of 'swoosh' effect](https://codepen.io/clarke-nicol/pen/JjKpwNw)
- [StackExchange q/a about rotating words with fancy layout and blur effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57179647/css-cycle-through-words)
- [StackExchange about literally flipping/rotating objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015568/how-to-rotate-flip-element-with-css)

### How I did it

Personally, I opted for a kind of simple pure CSS animation, which works like this:

HTML:

`<span id="replace-me"></span>.`

CSS:

```
#replace-me {
  color: #4353FF;
}


#replace-me:after {
  content: "entrepreneur";
  animation: spin 12s linear;
  /* loop */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    content: "maker";
  }
  25% {
    content: "entrepreneur";
  }
  50% {
    content: "founder";
  }
  75% {
    content: "creator";
  }
  100% {
    content: "indie hacker";
  }
}
```

The effect looks like [this](https://themakerswalk.website/) - this is a project of mine, so I may remove this reference if someone counts it as undue self promotion.

### Wrapping Up

Hope this points you in an helpful direction. Since you directly asked what it's called, my best guess would be something like `rotate between words` `switch out words` `replace words loop` `typewriter effect` or `cycle through words`. Might have a proper name though, so happy to stand corrected - otherwise maybe you can invent a cool one :)